# What's the question with lower opacity in question list?

Tags: support

Sometimes I see some question in the question list with lower opacity as below:

[image: Lower opacity question]

First I think it's a deleted question, but because I do not refresh the question page, the page sets a lower opacity to that, but it's wrong and the question loads when click on that.

Anybody could guide me what's that?

Comment: Hmmm I have never seen that

Comment: Are you ignoring any tags?